# How to retain a map view inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have a use case where a list and a map view share quite the same code base and show the same data. So I cannot separate them by using ListFragment and MapFragment as parent.

So I made a fragment that contains both views:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The user can toggle between list and map view. This works very well despite the fact that the map view cannot retain its markers on configuration changes. When the screen is rotated, the map view get's its initial state without markers and without zoom. All markers that where previously added are gone. When I used MapFragment I did not have this problem, it kind of retained itself.

Stripped down code:

```
public class ListAndMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private MapView mapView;

    public ListAndMapFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle arguments) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, arguments);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pillar_list, container, false);
        mapView = (MapView) root.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        if (arguments == null) {
            mapView.onCreate(null);
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        }

        return root;
    }

    private GoogleMap getMap() {
        return mapView.getMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to address this problem? One solution would be to replace all markers. However I would like to know if there is another approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Marker` object cannot be retained through configuration changes because it doesn't implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable` interface.

However, you can persist [**`MarkerOptions`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html) object because it is [**Parcelable**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and then recreate your `Marker`s from it. You can have a class field of type `MarkerOptions` for each of your `Marker`s and then re-populate the map on configuration changes (for example in `onSaveInstanceState`):

```
mapView.getMap().addMarker(MyMarkerOptions);
```

Another way would be to save your `Marker`s in a HashMap and re-use them on configuration changes.

[**`Here is another full example`**](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/retain-markers-on-screen-rotation-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-parcelable-latlng-points/) that uses `Parcelable LatLng` points to persist `Markers`.

The example works so when adding a marker it also adds the corresponding coordinates to an `ArrayList` as `LatLng` object. Then on configuration change, the `ArrayList` gets saved to a `Bundle` object in `onSaveInstanceState` and the `LatLng` objects get retrieved in `onCreate`.

---

**OP's note:**

So I went with the solution to implement `onSaveInstanceState` and drop `setRetainInstance(true)`. The benefit is that I can retain the map myself. However the disadvantage is that the map has to be fully initialized on each config change which makes the app slow for 1 or 2 seconds on e.g. screen rotation. But I am fine with this.

Comment: I assume I have to remove setRetainInstance because onSaveInstanceState will not be called?

Comment: @artworkadシ cool, i'm glad you managed to find a suitable solution. This problem is actually pretty known and there is no direct solution unfortunately https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4650 other than variations of solutions I've suggested here.